# Draw shapes in a shape recursively Fabric.js

Tags: javascript, recursion, canvas, fabricjs

I have to make a network map in js in which there are components included in component (etc..). I use canvas to do this with the Fabric.js library.

I get a json from an api like this :

```js
{
    "name": "BAY_01",
    "type": "Bay",
    "_links": [{
        "name": "SERVER_01",
        "type": "Server",
        "_links": [{
            "name": "CPU"
        }, {
            etc...
        }],
    }]
}
```

I think the best way to implement the draw of these components is to make it recursive but I don't know how to do this.

Can anyone help me to solve my issue?

Comment: How are you planning draw components? By name, by type? Can you include information inside JSON? Can you give us code what have you done so far?

Comment: I want to draw components by name but I don't already have done some code at this moment. One component is defined by : **name, type, fields and links**.
If two components are linked by an "included link" (it's just a field in my DB) like in my example : BAY_01 and SERVER_01 are linked by an included_link so BAY_01 contains a "_links" object that defined its links. At this moment, I just have to implement a cartography of a component and its links (included type only).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of using recursion by **name**. Basically you need to determine if a property of the JSON object is an array then call recursion function again, else check if property name is **"name"** then call function to draw shape by name:

```js
var obj = {
    "name": "BAY_01",
    "type": "Bay",
    "_links": [{
        "name": "SERVER_01",
        "type": "Server",
        "_links": [{
            "name": "CPU"
        }, {
           "name": "SERVER_02",
          "type": "Server",
          "_links": [{
             "name": "CPU2"
         }]
     }]
      }]
};

function goThroughtObject(obj, name) {
  var key;
  if (obj instanceof Array) {
    return obj.map(function(value) {
        if (typeof value === "object") {
          goThroughtObject(value, name)
        }
        return value;
    })
  } else {
    for (key in obj) {
      if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
       if (key === name){   
        drawByName(obj[key]);
        }
        if (obj[key] instanceof Array || (obj[key] !== null && obj[key].constructor === Object)) {
          goThroughtObject(obj[key], name);
        }
      } 
    }
  }
};

//implement fabricjs logic in this function
function drawByName (name) {
 console.log("Fabricjs will draw a: " + name);
}

goThroughtObject(obj, 'name');
```

Please remember to use `canvas.renderAll();` function after the recursion function as long as it will be better performance.

Comment: It is very helpfull thk you very much!